# Automatically Handling File Paths in Postman Collections When Transferring to Another Computer

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a file in my postman request, and the file's path is specific to my own computer. When I transfer this collection to a different computer, the old computer's path remains, and I have to change it again. How can I automatically find this path on the new computer instead of having to manually correct it?

If it's not possible, I'm considering placing the files on the company's local network and fetching them from there.